# Update Python value to Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

May I know how to solve the following error?

I found that the error occurs due to these lines of code

```
scope = ###
creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file("v1Timetable.json", scopes=scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
google_sh = client.open("v1Timetable")
sheet1 = google_sh.get_worksheet(1)

for k in range(0, numberOfGroups):
    for l in c.GetGroups():
        if l == instance.GetStudentsGroupById(str(k + 1)):
            # info is updated here
            if(grNumber == 0):
                sheet1.update_cell(d + 1, t + 1, str(info))   # (row, col)
            if(grNumber == 1):
                sheet1.update_cell(d + 8, t + 1, str(info))   # (row, col)
            if(grNumber == 2):
                sheet1.update_cell(d + 15, t + 1, str(info))   # (row, col)
            if(grNumber == 3):
               sheet1.update_cell(d + 22, t + 1, str(info))   # (row, col)
```

> gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded
> for quota metric 'Write requests' and limit 'Write requests per minute
> per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:332000645656'.", 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED',
> 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo',
> 'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com',
> 'metadata': {'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'consumer':
> 'projects/332000645656', 'quota_limit':
> 'WriteRequestsPerMinutePerUser', 'quota_metric':
> 'sheets.googleapis.com/write_requests'}}]}

Comment: Read the error. "Quota exceeded". Learn to read.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets has a maximum read and write quota per user per time unit, and it seems like you are exceeding it. It looks like you might be updating the cells one by one, thus sending many write requests instead of fewer big ones. Instead of updating the data one cell at a time, try updating one range of cells at a time. Assuming you're using the library Gspread, see the documentation here: [link](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#updating-cells).

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by updating the answer into an array.

Then use sheet.update('A1',arr.tolist()) to update the value in the array into the Google Spreadsheet.